# How to communicate current item in a v-for loop to sibling component

Tags: ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I am building an image gallery app using VueJS and one component of the gallery is a scrolling carousel that I have taken from the Vuetify library. The carousel looks like this -

```
<v-carousel :cycle="false" icon="none">
  <v-carousel-item v-for="(image,index) in imageList" :src="image"
  :key="index">
  </v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
```

When I scroll through the carousel, I want the current image being displayed, i.e. the current src binding for the `v-carousel-item` to be communicated to a sibling component.

I am having problems with extracting the current src into a javascript variable - once I do that I can figure out how to get it to the other component.

Please help.

Comment: I have been told that the current version of vuetify doesn't support this - future versions will include a v-model statement that will bind to the current  item.

Comment: A newer version of vuetify is out that lets you bind the current item of the carousel through a v-model statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<v-carousel v-model="carouselIndex">
    <v-carousel-item v-for="(src,i) in images" :src="src" :key="i"></v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
<span>Current Index: {{carouselIndex}}</span>
```

Comment: Please provide information why your code should work

Comment: The carouselIndex gets updated with the key. I can't say much more except it works for me.